# JSDoc: How to add functions to Nav Bar

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

In jsdoc default template, nav bar is constructed in `publish.js` `buildNav` function.

e.g.

`nav += buildMemberNav(members.events, 'Events', seen, linkto);`

However, there's no `members.functions`.

I'd like to know how to list all the functions (under every Namespace, class) in the nav bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a template https://github.com/nijikokun/minami/blob/master/publish.js#L298-L333 , where they create a sub list of methods for each class, as the reference.

Say, if we want to list all the functions under every namespace in the nav bar, we can have the following code to add the related html

```
var methods = find({kind:'function', memberof: item.longname});
```

`item` here in our case, is `member.namespace`

```
if (methods.length) {
    itemsNav += "<ul class='methods'>";
    methods.forEach(function (method) {
        itemsNav += "<li data-type='method'>";
        itemsNav += linkto(method.longname, method.name);
        itemsNav += "</li>";
    });
    itemsNav += "</ul>";
}
```